# .NET WebApi - How to return a local json file as a response for a controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api in .NET MVC with a method that is supposed to return JSON. This JSON content should be stored in a local file in the project.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("my_content")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
    {
        // return json file here
    }
```

I'm fairly new to .NET development, so my questions are:

1) Where should I keep this JSON file in the project structure

2) What's the best way to return this JSON file stored locally?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just have static content?

Answer (score 0):

You have plenty of options. None which is the single truth.

- As a file (File type set to Content). Use a File.Read to read from current directory.
- As an embedded resource. Use ResourceManager to load resource embedded in assembly.
- Use Settings.cs (personally don't like this one)
- Use a static content. (this would be fine, depending on the size of the content)

You can google each to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Json file inside your project and your get method should be like this,

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            var json = File.ReadAllText(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/JsonData/product.json"));

            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
            };
        }
```